# Renaming JSON subkeys using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to help a JSON structure format from an existing project, and the goal is to rename some subkeys not the value. The JSON format like this

```js
{
  "table-name": "Kiwi",
  "created-on": "November 20, 2021",
  "token": "lsUVozOB2TxhvMv",
  "icons": "default",
  "links": "default",
  "extra": "default",
  "mode": "Private",
  "collaborators": [],
  "columns": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "text",
      "extra": ""
    },
    "Info": {
      "type": "longtext",
      "extra": ""
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "droplist",
      "extra": {
        "fr": "Pending",
        "sc": "On-going",
        "th": "Completed",
        "fo": "Cancelled"
      }
    }
  },
  "data": [{
      "Name": "Team Reports",
      "Info": "Submitting marketing materials reports",
      "Status": "Completed"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Fabia HR",
      "Info": "Brian asking for a report",
      "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Fabia",
      "Info": "Meeting with CEO @cafe 9:00",
      "Status": "Cancelled"
    }
  ]
}
```

And we're looking into the `columns` to rename the `Name` into `Task` and still keep the other. After using array push and slice the keys, I'm getting `0` as the keys and "Task as subkeys like

```js
"0":{
  "Task":{
    "type":"text",
    "extra":""
  },
```

The code looks like this. Please do share your solutions in your spare time, thank you in advance, really appreciate any attention. Total noob here 
PHP:

```php
$file = file.json;  
$jsn = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsn, true);
 
//get name data array 
$sub_data = $data['columns']['Name'];

$new_rename = array(
    "Task" => $sub_data;
);

array_push($data['columns'],$new_rename);

//now delete old "Name";
array_slice($data['columns'],'Name')

//save stuff
$jsn = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file,$jsn);
```

Comment: if you're parsing the JSON to a PHP data structure as your very first step, your question has nothing to do with "JSON data", and is simply about renaming one or more properties somewhere in a PHP object. Ask about that, instead (after searching for how to do that, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're working with JSON objects and thus PHP associative arrays (as opposed to numerically indexed), all you really need to do is set the new property and unset the old one

```php
$data["columns"]["Task"] = $data["columns"]["Name"];
unset($data["columns"]["Name"]);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/7pBpZ

Comment: Thank you so much. Very appreciated. One quick follow-up is there a chance to place it in the same position?

Comment: Why? The position of named object properties is generally arbitrary

Comment: It wasn't arbitrary because it was connected on the ```$data['data']``` on the JSON.. Means position on ```$data['columns']``` as cells and ```$data['data']``` as row, it's a table project, any way you did help a lot figuring out, I will just to figure out to re-position it again.. Much loved!

Comment: If the order is important, it should be in an array

Comment: yeah that's the last option were thinking.. but do you think ```array_replace``` will keep the position like after adding ```$data['Task']```  then replacing ```$data['Name']```?